# Linux command to get mDNS Service discovery and to get its IP Address

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ip-address, mdns

I am broadcasting mDNS service from my WiFi module. I need to discover that in my Linux PC and get its IP address.

1. I used mdns-scan command and I am getting the Service name listed.
2. I used avahi-browse --all and I am getting my service name listed.
3. But How do I get the IP address of that service? That is my requirement.
4. In Android applications I am able to get full details of the services. How do I get it in linux?
5. I tried if config -a and nmap also.

Answer (score 6):

> I used avahi-browse --all and I am getting my service name listed.

Use **`avahi-resolve --name`** to map the hostname to its IP addresses.

Alternatively, to make mDNS `*.local` hostnames resolvable system-wide, you can use [nss-mdns](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/nss-mdns/) (using Avahi backend) or nss-resolve (using systemd-resolved backend). This will allow any application to use mDNS names as if they were regular DNS.

> In Android applications I am able to get full details of the services. How do I get it in linux?

In Android applications you are using the OS-provided API. Likewise, in Linux, you should be using the proper OS-provided API – either [libavahi-client](https://www.avahi.org/doxygen/html/client-browse-services_8c-example.html) or [libavahi-glib](https://www.avahi.org/doxygen/html/glib-integration_8c-example.html) – *not* random CLI tools glued together. All of the tools you listed are for manual usage by sysadmins, not for scripting.

DNS-SD stores the service's additional information in TXT records. As shown in the API examples, the "resolve callback" function will automatically receive an array of TXT records as a parameter without having to do anything extra.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you need this for an automation script in which case this may not be the best solution, but a simple `ping` command will also get you the IP address.

See this example:

```bash
$ ping lightpizero.local
PING lightpizero.local (192.168.0.104) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

The address in this case is clearly `192.168.0.104`